# backbone groupby collection is not rendered

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js

I still struggling with render my grouped collection. In my console I can see collection with error. I wanna render each category name and each items in this category. Thanks for opinions !!! This will be very helpful....

There is my whole code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Backbone test</title>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0-rc1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
<header>
</header>
<content>  
   <div class="jumbotron">
       <div class="container">
           <h1>My Items!</h1>
       </div>
   </div>
   <div id="items"></div>                       
</content>
<footer>
</footer>
<script id="allItemTemlate" type="text/template">
       <ul>
       <% _.each( data, function( category, i ){  %>
           <li>
               <h3><%= i %></h3>
               <ul>
               <% _.each( category, function( item ){ %>
               <li>
                 <%= item.title %>
               </li>
               <% }) %>
               </ul>
         </li>
       <% }) %>
       </ul>   
</script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.5.1/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.0.0/backbone-min.js"></script>
<script>
(function() {
    window.App = {
        Models: {},
        Collections: {},
        Views: {},
        Router: {}
    };
    window.vent = _.extend({}, Backbone.Events);
})();

// !models.js

App.Models.Item = Backbone.Model.extend({});

// !collections.js

App.Collections.Items = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: App.Models.Item,
    url: 'api/items.json'
});

// !views.js 

App.Views.Items = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#items',
    initialize: function() {
    this.render();
     var groups = _.groupBy(this.collection.toJSON(), 'category');
     console.log(groups);
     template = _.template( document.getElementById('allItemTemlate').innerHTML, { data : groups } );

    },
    render: function() {
    document.getElementById('items').innerHTML = template;
    },
});

// !router.js

App.Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        '':'index',
    },
    index: function() {
        console.log('index page !');
    },
});

new App.Router;
Backbone.history.start();
App.items = new App.Collections.Items;
App.items.fetch().then(function() {
    new App.Views.Items({ collection: App.items });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `_.template` and `this.render();` are called before `_.groupBy`, so `data.groups == null`.

Comment: thanks Pawel I edit have edited this issue but now I have in console Uncaught ReferenceError: template is not defined

Comment: You need `template` in `this.render()`, but you call `this.render()` before assigning anything to `template`. BTW you create a global `template` variable, it'd be better to use `this.template`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be more aware of execution order. For example if you need a variable in `render`, you shouldn't call `render` before setting that variable. I also propose some changes.

```
App.Views.Items = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#items',
    initialize: function() {
     // listen to collection change event and re-render then
     this.listenTo( this.collection, "change", this.render );

     // changes: this.template instead of global template
     // and not executing it yet, but creating a function
     this.template = _.template( document.getElementById('allItemTemlate').innerHTML );
     this.render();
    },
    // a separate method to get the groupped collection
    getGroups : function(){
       return _.groupBy(this.collection.toJSON(), 'category');
    },
    render: function() {
        // here the template gets executed and writtn to element's innerHTML
        // also removed getElementById, as it is readily available as this.el
        this.el.innerHTML = this.template({ data : this.getGroups() });
    },
});
```

Comment: thanks very much pawel !!! You make my days much better :) Do you have some time for small job ?

Comment: I need only this grouped data in accordion style and in each model will be delete button so when somebody click to this button item will be deleted from view and from server

Comment: @Makromat see edited answer. Added listening to `collection.change` and re-rendering the view.

Comment: wait, no badge for the first love confession? :(

Comment: Sorry ? badge ? I mark your answer solved... or there is something else ? I will do it :D

Comment: @Makromat it was a joke, SO gives badges for different achievements, so why not for this one? ;)

Comment: You are from Poland ... you live by the sea ?

Comment: Pawel can you contact me  ? Thanks very much